# PWA: Polling for data in the background

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My PWA App needs to poll for new "Notifications" from an API while the app is being used or in the background.

I am using **NuxtJS** with **Vuex** and already have an action (Promise) that performs the request and adds to state and as well as Indexed DB.

I need to call this action every 5 minutes and create notifications for id's in the response that I have not yet seen.

I can do the notification part, but I do not know **how to call my Vuex action**. Can I dispatch the action or do I need to import my promise into the service worker somehow?

In Nuxt PWA [`nuxt.config.js`] you can add files to the `pwa.workbox.importScripts` array, but including one of my `store` files does not work, since the service worker is looking for files in it's own directory and my store files have been compressed e.g.

```
pwa: {
  workbox: {
    importScripts: [
      'custom_sw.js',
      '~/store/test.js'
    ]
  ...
  }
}
```

If there is no way for me to do either, I'll just have to rewrite the fetching and parsing code, but this is quite inefficient.

I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3):

The code that runs inside the Service Worker is in a separate *scope* from the one that runs on the page. In other words: if you have some variables/functions/whatever on your "regular JS code" (JS running in the window scope), you cannot access them from inside the Service Worker scope and vice versa. They are two completely separate scopes of execution.

In order to "share" something between these two scopes of execution is to use the postMessage API. With postMessage, you can send messages from the window scope to the Service Worker and back. Basically you register event listeners for messages and use the postMessage API to send something to the other side. Then, at the receiving end, you may do whatever you want.

When talking about Vuex actions and Service Worker something like this is most likely what you're after:

- add message event listener on page (window scope)
- Service Worker send a message to the page with some info (notification msg: blaa blaa) using postMessage API
- event listener runs a function with the message from the SW
- that function dispatches a Vuex action with the message

The key here is that you cannot dispatch the Vuex actions from inside your Service Worker since the code running there doesn't have any access to the Vuex store. You solve this by sending a message via postMessage. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage